# Am I supposed to run BFG on the mirrored repo or the original?

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history, bfg-repo-cleaner

I want to delete two files from my git repo that aren't there anymore.

I put them in, committed, and tried to push but they were too large. So I took them out, and kept working, then committed, tried to push, but it still gave me the same error. I figured they're still in the history somewhere.

I think I made the problem worse because I kept working in that branch and made 1 more commit. Then I merged that branch back to the master branch.

So I searched for a solution and found [bfg](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/).

But the instructions on the page don't make sense to me.

First off,

```
$ git clone --mirror git://example.com/some-big-repo.git
```

Where am I supposed to clone from? My remote repo on github.com doesn't have the commits and the merge I did since I added the large files. But the instructions make it seem like I'm supposed to get it from there anyway. (I cloned from my local repo.)

Next,

```
$ java -jar bfg.jar --strip-blobs-bigger-than 100M some-big-repo.git
```

Is `some-big-repo.git` the mirrored repo or the normal local repo?
(I used the mirrored repo for this.)

And then I checked that my history had been updated and tried,

```
$ cd some-big-repo.git
$ git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

(I was in the mirrored clone for this) I got an error.

```
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error: 
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: error: other way.
remote: error: 
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
To /home/cole/main_repo
 + 94b9a0d...c7c4317 work -> work (forced update)
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to '/home/cole/main_repo'
```

This makes sense to me. Yeah I do currently have `master` checked out. But then, what else was I supposed to do? I can only see problems happening if I try it another way.

Comment: I actually got it to work in a surprisingly simple way. I just had to do `git push https://github.com/<the remote>`. Then it didn't try to push to the local repo and give me those errors. But when I pulled a fresh clone from repo, it was missing some things. I just added them from my local repo and committed and pushed. Now I'm all fresh and clean. I hope that's how it was supposed to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should clone/mirror the repo that you eventually plan to replace the commits-in, but there's an underlying assumption that this repo is also a bare repo.  This would usually be a remote repo, but you might also clone a local repo to save bandwidth.

The underlying assumption is that the repo where you will eventually store your cleaned repository is *also* a bare repo.  Server-based repos e.g. GitHub are usually exactly that.

In your case it sounds like you have cloned a local, non-bare (contains a HEAD and working-copy) repo, either to save bandwidth, or because it is the repo that contains the commits you wish to clean.  Either way, in order to push back into a non-bare repo, you need to make sure you don't have any refs you want to push checked-out, including master.

From your comment it looks like you found the solution, which is to push-back to the eventual origin repo, which will likely be a bare repo.

Answer (score 3):

First 3 steps with BFG:

1. Download BFG using the following command in terminal: `brew install bfg`
2. Clone a fresh copy of your repo, using the `--mirror` flag.

   ```
   git clone --mirror git://example.com/some-big-repo.git
   ```

   The mirror flag allows you to make a full copy of the Git database without actually copying down the files of the repo.
3. `bfg --the-options-you-want the-mirror-repo-you-just-cloned.git`

Adapted from [this manual by an IBM engineer](https://github.com/IBM/BluePic/wiki/Using-BFG-Repo-Cleaner-tool-to-remove-sensitive-files-from-your-git-repo). Don't `cd` into the repo as it says on step 3, otherwise you'll get an error "the-mirror-repo-you-just-cloned.git is not a valid Git repository."

Comment: For those stuck who get  *fatal: not a git repository* message on reflog and prune. You need to in your cloned directory and then **go a level deeper** into the `myrepo.git` directory. When you go in this directory you will see in Bash it says `(Bare:master)`. Then the reflog and prune will work.

Comment: it said to me that it was not a valid repository. I was inside the repo. You should not be inside the repo.