# ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) (after trying to push large file)

Tags: git, github

I was trying to push a large file and was given `remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.`. I added that file path to .gitignore and tried again and was then given `! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)`.

I am the owner of this repo and the only one working on it. Everything worked fine before I added the large file.

Comment: (@grg GitHub themselves enforce this automatically.) You're pushing multiple commits, one or more of which have the large file. You can make a new commit that does not have the large file, but if this simply adds on to the commits that *do* have the large file, you still cannot push the entire chain of commits. You need to *discard* the bad commit(s), which automatically also discards all subsequent commits; if you need subsequent commits, you'll have to copy them to new and improved commits first.

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+large+files+detected or eg https://stackoverflow.com/q/37767720/1256452