# remote rejected (pre-receive hook declined)

Tags: html, git, github, terminal, git-lfs

I accidentally tried to upload a zip folder I made, essentially doubling the media I was trying to push and this happened. I've tried searching on commands how to fix this and can't seem to find one.

I've tried that YouTube video that says git push -A
I've tried git ' lfs track "*.ext" '
And a couple others I can't recall[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove big (>100MB) file from a GitHub repository and push successfully?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37767720/how-to-remove-big-100mb-file-from-a-github-repository-and-push-successfully)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [undo your previous commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/927386/13172506).
From the linked answer:

```
$ git commit -m "Something terribly misguided"             # (1)
$ git reset HEAD~                                          # (2)
<< edit files as necessary >>                              # (3)
$ git add ...                                              # (4)
$ git commit -c ORIG_HEAD                                  # (5)
```